Next.js app using ImageKit: 404 Error When Loading Images
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
I've set it up so that when I load an image, it should create a link, but nothing happens. The image doesn't display, and I can't figure out what's causing this issue.
Does anyone know what might be going wrong or how to solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Please help me solve this issue i am stuck in  the middle
